# How to create customRouteWrapper for Route in React Router v6?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I need to have a customWrapper for my Route in react-router v6 because I need to pass different props and layouts. before that in v5 I didn't have issue in create a custom function that returns a `Route` and I use that function inside `Routes` but in v6 I got this error:

```
Error: [RouteWrapper] is not a <Route> component. All component children of <Routes> must be a <Route> or <React.Fragment>
```

I tried to use fragments inside Routes but no luck same error shows up.
here's my implementation:

```js
return (
        <Layout {...layoutProps} onAnimationEnd={onAnimationEnd} isInTransitionStage={isInTransitionStage}>
            <Routes location={displayLocation}>
                <React.Fragment>
                    <RouteWrapper
                        path='/'
                        // component={HomePage}
                        layout={MainLayout}
                        setLayout={setLayout}
                        setLayoutProps={setLayoutProps}
                    />
                </React.Fragment>
            </Routes>
        </Layout>
    );
};

const RouteWrapper = ({path, component, layout}) => {
    return <Route path={path} element={layout} />;
};
```

Answer (score 3):

The [doc](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#routes-and-route) for version 6 says
If you'd prefer to define your routes as regular JavaScript objects instead of using JSX, try [`useRoutes`](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/hooks/use-routes) instead.

```
import * as React from "react";
import { useRoutes } from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  let element = useRoutes([
    {
      path: "/",
      element: <Home />,
      // children: [/* nested routes */]
    },
    { path: "your-path", element: <RouteWrapper /> }
  ]);

  return element;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use `RouterProvider` and wrap my routes by doing two things

- creating extended route object (RouteObject with my own props)
- mapping them

  - by adding wrapper with protection and custom logic
  - filtering back from ExtendedRouteObject to RouteObject

Use code below or [npm-package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-dom-wrapping) based on snippet below

```
// Overwrite is my custom type in order to override any type i need
type TExtendedRouteObject = Overwrite<
  RouteObject,
  {
    children?: TExtendedRouteObject[];
  }
> & {
  /**
   * In order to set to document.title
   */
  title: string;
};

const mapExtendedRoutes = (routeObjects: TExtendedRouteObject[]): RouteObject[] => {
  if (routeObjects.length) {
    return routeObjects.map(route => {
      if (route.children?.length) {
        return omit({
          ...route,
          element: <RouteWrapper {...route} />,
          children: mapExtendedRoutes(route.children),
        },
        ['title'],
      ) as RouteObject;
      }

      return omit({ // omit from lodash.omit
        ...route,
        element: <RouteWrapper {...route} />,
      }) as RouteObject;
    });
  }

  return [];
};

const RouteWrapper: FC<TExtendedRouteObject> = ({ element, title }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    document.title = title;
  }, [title]);

  // your custom logic goes here

  return <>{element}</>;
};

const extendedRoutes: TExtendedRouteObject[] = [
  {
    path: '/',
    title: 'Homepage',
    element: <Dashboard />,
    children: [...],
  },
...
];

const routes: RouteObject[] = mapExtendedRoutes(extendedRoutes);

const router = createBrowserRouter(routes);
// then pass it to <RouterProvider router={router} />
```